# jquery datepicker minutes stucked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery datepicker plugin to let users pick the date and time.

I'm importing it from cdn:

On html form I pointed to the datetimepicker ID.

```js
jQuery('#datetimepicker01').datetimepicker({
    lang: 'pt',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    todayButton: true,
    defaultSelect: true,
    mask: true,
    timepicker: true,
    step: 15,
    format: 'Y-m-d H:m'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input id="datetimepicker01" type="text" >
```

When I pick a date / time, can someone explaint me why I always get hour:08 minutes (lol)? Example: yyyy-mm-dd 21:08 ... If I pick 21 hour and 30 minutes, It will assume 21:08 ...

Thanks for any help given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong format, you have to use `format: 'Y-m-d H:i'`

So i change `H:m` to `H:i`

**Working Snippet**

```js
jQuery('#datetimepicker01').datetimepicker({
    lang: 'pt',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    todayButton: true,
    defaultSelect: true,
    mask: true,
    timepicker: true,
    step: 15,
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input id="datetimepicker01" type="text" >
```

Comment: omg... Thanks!! It's to late to figure small details. Going to bed! Thanks again. Regards